# Calibrate Monitor using VGA connector

Tags: display, vga

Unfortunately I am stuck with a monitor at work which only has a VGA connection, no DVI input is available.  What's the best way of calibrating the monitor so I can get the best sharpness and color?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would use a hardware calibrator like the an [Xrite Eye One Display 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JLO31M) (there are less expensive ones available) to accurately calibrate your monitor's color. Barring that, there are some software-based calibration utilities available as well. I'd give [Calibrize](http://www.calibrize.com/) a try (it is free!).